# Updating Batch files via Dropbox

Tags: windows, batch-file, dropbox

So, there isn't anything big that I'm really going to use this for, but I've  have made a little batch (.bat) program that I thought would be awesome if I had this feature in it.

I don't want anything that is going to mess up my LAN network, so try to make it as simple
as possible.

So my idea is that I want it so when the program starts it scans for an update (which will be found on Dropbox), then ask the user if they want to update, then it will install an update file and delete the old one. If anyone knows a way to do this safely, please tell me, thanks!

I have a tiny bit of an idea on how this is possible, but it is not very efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a file on your computer and one on Dropbox and sometimes you want to edit it from another computer and then when you get back home and start up the program it will check whether the Dropbox file is more up to date than the one you have on your computer?

I think the easiest way would be to either use a special file name, like, myBatchFile_update.bat or something and then make your program check for that file in your Dropbox folder. If it's there, copy it and then rename it to myBatchFile.bat or something. Also rename update file. You may want to look up `copy` and `xcopy` and `ren`, first.

Another way would be to keep the "if updated" information inside of the file in a function (although it's hardly functions in batch). Or you could just keep another file called for example is_updated.bat where you keep information about whether it's updated or not. You echo something like `set update=true` (if it's updated) to the update file when it has updated and when you have edited the program you also edit the update file so that it says false. Then, when you need the information, you just `call` the update file.

Comment: But still, how do I get it to look if the Dropbox file is there. That is what I am asking

Comment: First you need to know where your Dropbox folder is located. You have to either `cd` (change directory) to where your file is: `cd C:\whatever\dropboxfolderstuff` and then you use `if exist your_file.bat`. Or you could just do `if exist C:\whatever\dropboxfolderstuff\your_file.bat`.

Comment: Um, I still don't think you understand. I'm talking about the Website Dropbox, the Internet. On Dropbox.com.        I wanna upload the update onto Dropbox.com and then get the users file to check for the update and see if it is on Dropbox